# How to get the sum of foreign key table as a value in the primary table row in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to get the sum of foreign key table as a value in the primary table row in sqlalchemy?

Consider table 1:

```
id(PK)   name    description
-----------------------------

 1       test1      desc1
 2       test2      desc2
```

Consider Table 2:

```
id       value
-----------------
 1         5
 1         6
 2         7
 2         8
```

**Desired Output**

```
id     name   desc    sum(value)
----------------------------------
 1     test1  desc1        11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func

query = (
    db.session.query(func.sum(Table2.value))
    .join(Table1)
    .filter(Table1.id == 1)
)
print(query.all())
```

Output: [(11.0,)]

Comment: [Tables Schema](https://imgur.com/a/T8ENcbk)

I have one more doubt, I have three tables with the schema as defined in the image url, I want id, title, content, published, created_at from posts table, username from Users table and sum of total votes for a post 

In the votes table, for every vote by a user, a new entry is created consisting of post id and user id